# how to populate an popup when a checkbox is checked jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a datatable, and there are n number of checkboxes, Whenever I click a check box I need a popup occuring with some X content.

Here is my code

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function () {

             if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

                 var htmlStr = '<div class="form"><form>First Name:<input type="text" maxlength="20"></input><br />Last Name:<input type="text" maxlength="20"></input></form></div>';

                 $.fancybox(htmlStr, {
                     'width': 950,
                     'height': 1100,
                     'autoScale': false,
                     'transitionIn': 'none',
                     'transitionOut': 'none',
                     'hideOnContentClick': false
                 });
             }
         });
```

There is an error in browser console

[image]

The fancybox Library I have used is

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.1.20/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.1.20/jquery.fancybox.min.css"
    type="text/css" />
```

I dont know where is the issue,
Help me out for this.
Thanks

Comment: Fancybox js has not been included probably.

Comment: its probably because you didnt incluide fancybox in your project

Comment: You need to add the script and css :`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.0.47/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.0.47/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
`

Comment: Please check the question again I have updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call open function of fancy box.

Here is a solution. Let me know if it works. Here you can test https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mwNgqX

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function () {
             if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                 var htmlStr = '<div class="form"><form>First Name:<input type="text" maxlength="20"></input><br />Last Name:<input type="text" maxlength="20"></input></form></div>';

                 $.fancybox.open(htmlStr, {
                     'width': 950,
                     'height': 1100,
                     'autoScale': false,
                     'transitionIn': 'none',
                     'transitionOut': 'none',
                     'hideOnContentClick': false
                 });
             }
         });
```